# How to move Shop Now Button's position?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, template, frontend

Shop Now button is coming from `addtocart.phtml` file.

I want to display Shop Now button after image. After image, content is coming from `view.phtml` file.

[image: product preview]

In `catalog.xml` file , I am trying to move block but no effect

```
   <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>  
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

I want to put Shop Now Button after media file.

Comment: You have to move codes in template (phtml) files.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri - How to move codes from addtocart.phtml to view.phtml file? While moving it is giving me error.

Comment: No no, you have to move within the template. Could you add your view.phtml? (Your screenshot looks like list.phtml though)

Comment: @AdarshKhatri - The screenshot which I have sent is of view.phtml

Comment: @AdarshKhatri - Thank you very much. Your answer is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the position of the add to cart button, you should change the code in template files, not in layout files.

You can go to `view.phtml` file and move the cart calling code as you need.

Cart calling code may look something similar to this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto');?>
//OR
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart');?>
```

**Remember when you move this code, it must be inside `<form>` nodes.**

This should help you.